# Best Feature extraction for at the end retrieving audio

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-construction

I work on a machine learning algo, which basically learns sequences in an audio .wav and generates the most “logical” sequences. The algorithm learns features, so I generate MFCCs from the audio file. But at the end it’s impossible to do MFCCs to .wav properly.

I read this paper [1] which says, yeah MFCCs lose a lot of information and give other feature extraction techniques but I don’t really know how to implement them in python.

So if you know some good feature extraction techniques for retrieving/reconstruct audio, with which I can choose the number of coefficients and how many times a vector of these coefficients represents, it would be so much help for me !

I Have test, the Librosa library which can generate MFCC and reconstruct audio with them but the MFCCs generated have weird dimensions like for 12 coef, you get a matrix 12 lines and 1000 columns, or i want the transpose of this matrix.

Thanks.

[1] Gonzalez, Ruben. (2013). Better Than MFCC Audio Classification Features. 10.1007/978-1-4614-3501-3_24.

Comment: If you want the transpose of the MFCC matrix, just access it with mfcc.T

Comment: The DTF step in going from mel spectrogram to MFCC is quite destructive. Try skipping that and work directly on the mel spectrogram. One can also upsample changes on the mel spectrogram to the STFT spectrogram, for even less noise